# What would cause a record to go missing in just a particular index in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

While diagnosing an issue I managed to observe a record flit in and out of existence depending on my where clause; (ie the index used).

Presumably this is a corrupted index? 
What could have caused this and how can I prevent it? 
How should I rebuild the index safely?
How can I detect if any other indexes on this or other tables are affects?

Here is some output from the postgres console:

```
us_website=> SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE id=190035;
   id   | company_id
--------+------------
 190035 |      24561
(1 row)

us_website=> SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE company_id=24561 AND id=190035;
   id   | company_id
--------+------------
 190035 |      24561
(1 row)

us_website=> SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE company_id=24561;
   id   | company_id
--------+------------
 325812 |      24561
 325821 |      24561
 325820 |      24561
 325819 |      24561
 325818 |      24561
 325817 |      24561
 325816 |      24561
 325815 |      24561
 325814 |      24561
 325813 |      24561
 325811 |      24561
 325810 |      24561
 310981 |      24561
 190034 |      24561
 278479 |      24561
 278478 |      24561
 278477 |      24561
 278476 |      24561
 278475 |      24561
 190033 |      24561
 278472 |      24561
 278471 |      24561
  43139 |      24561
(23 rows)

us_website=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE id=190035;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_summaries_on_id on summaries  (cost=0.00..8.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = 190035)
 Total runtime: 0.062 ms
(3 rows)

us_website=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE company_id=24561 AND id=190035;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_summaries_on_id on summaries  (cost=0.00..8.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (id = 190035)
   Filter: (company_id = 24561)
 Total runtime: 0.044 ms
(4 rows)

us_website=> EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT id, company_id from summaries WHERE company_id=24561;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using index_summaries_on_company_id on summaries  (cost=0.00..102.86 rows=31 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.049 rows=23 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (company_id = 24561)
 Total runtime: 0.080 ms
(3 rows)
```

Note that in the query just by company_id the record is NOT returned. Also note that this query uses a particular index that the others don't use.

Comment: Have you tried ANALYZE; and VACUUM; ? The postgresql page on REINDEX  is very helpful in explaining options for correcting corrupted indexes.

Comment: "REINDEX INDEX index_summaries_on_company_id;" Fixed this issue up in 1 second flat (even for hundreds of thousands of rows). But I'm more worried about how this could have happened. Any ideas? Might never know I guess. Cosmic rays? :)

Comment: What is your **exact** Postgres version? `select  version()` will show you

Comment: 9.2.9 (NB: we're currently upgrading postgres across our infrastructure, but this db server is pretty far behind!) I have since read that newer postgres versions have better protection against index corruption. Guess we'd better get that upgrade done!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my checklist for index corruption:

1. Overheating CPU (believe it or not, most common cause I have seen so far!)
2. Bad RAM
3. Issues of bad writes to storage.  Perhaps some strange misdetection of a wal write that did not complete in an index?  Never seen this one in the wild though.